# Update a column based on column in the same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write an update statement that will update the newTableNo column based on the other columns in the same table.

This is what I have.

```
childNo | parentNo |TableID |newTableNo
--------+----------+--------+---------+
26      |    NULL  |   750  | NULL    |
27      |    NULL  |   751  | NULL    |
28      |    27    |   752  | NULL    |
29      |    27    |   753  | NULL    |
30      |    27    |   754  | NULL    |
34      |    NULL  |   800  | NULL    |
```

This is expected.

```
childNo | parentNo |TableID |newTableNo
--------+----------+--------+---------+
26      |    NULL  |   750  | NULL    |
27      |    NULL  |   751  | NULL    |
28      |    27    |   752  | 751     |
29      |    27    |   753  | 751     |
30      |    27    |   754  | 751     |
34      |    NULL  |   800  | NULL    |
```

- If parentNo is NULL then newTableNo is defintely NULL
- If parentNo is not null then it has related childNo(s)

Format table

Comment: Please format your question properly. What value do you expect to see in the childNo column if the parentNo column is not NULL?

Comment: Your question is not really clear on what result you actually want. What are the criteria you are looking for, in which columns are you looking for it, and what result do you want based on those things?

Comment: I rolled back your edit; it overwrote Tony's edit but actually made the formatting worse

Comment: Sorry for the bad format. This my first question. I edited now.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @table table (childNo int, parentNo int, TableID int, NewTableNo int)
insert into @table
values
(26,NULL,750,NULL),
(27,NULL,751,NULL),
(28,27,752,NULL),
(29,27,753,NULL),
(30,27,754,NULL),
(34,NULL,800,NULL)



update t2
set t2.newTableNo = t.TableID
from @table t
full join @table t2 on t2.parentNo = t.childNo

select * from @table
```

You could also do this with an `inner join`

```
update t
set t.newTableNo = t2.TableID
from @table t
INNER JOIN @table t2 ON t.parentNo = t2.childNo
where t.parentNo is not null


select * from @table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script to update newTableNo column

```
declare @table table (childNo int, parentNo int, TableID int, NewTableNo int)
insert into @table
values
(26,NULL,750,NULL),
(27,NULL,751,NULL),
(28,27,752,NULL),
(29,27,753,NULL),
(30,27,754,NULL),
(34,NULL,800,NULL)


UPDATE t
SET t.newTableNo = tt.TableID
FROM @table t
INNER JOIN @table tt ON t.parentNo = tt.childNo
WHERE t.parentNo IS NOT NULL

select * from @table
```

Comment: scsimon declare table variable make this answer more clear and easy to test. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use:

```
UPDATE t1
SET newTableNo = parents.TableID
FROM
t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE parentNo IS null) parents
ON
  Parents.childno = t1.parentNo
```

Answer (score 0):

To update :

```
UPDATE mytable SET newTableNo = t2.TableID FROM mytable 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT childNo,TableID  FROM  mytable) t2 ON t2.childNo = parentNo
```

Not that if parentNo or TableID updates, newTableNo may turn obsolete.
You can select that value easily without create an actual data column:

```
SELECT t1.childNo, t1.parentNo, t1.TableID, t2.TableID AS newTableNo
FROM mytable t1
LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON t2.childNo = t1.parentNo
```